# To test googlepay with payment tokenization method as direct in test environment requires PCI DSS?

Tags: google-pay

I am trying to figure out a way to implement googlepay with\without PCI DSS and want to know if "test" environment also has to have PCI DSS if direct tokenization method is used

Answer (score 1):

It seems to work for me in `TEST` mode without PCI DSS: https://jsfiddle.net/35pseb2n/

```js
const tokenizationSpecification = {
  type: 'DIRECT',
  parameters: {
    'protocolVersion': 'ECv2',
    'publicKey': 'BMzk6xvwPgU8vjB6O/HnFFkMQL/w17yIoKy/6KuRYjOrh0eV12xM6guaYPHdgMHyUzTm9/Vi7KRu4tuRmhm6nv8=',
  }
};
```

Although I haven't actually tried decrypting it, and I can't confirm if the contents of the token are representative of what I chose in the UI

Answer (score 0):

we dont need PCI DSS for test environment for direct integration
gpay will ask for the PCI attestation when we are submitting the gpay integration